# Generating masks with same name as original images

Tags: python, matlab

I have a little problem,
I have annotations (ground truth) in MATLAB file and currently it works (process of generating masks) but I want to masks have exactly the same name as real images (which names are defined in `gt.mat['imnames']`.

But images are in one folder `/home/SynthText/` and there are 200 folders where in 1 folder are 4k images, in folder 2 are another 4k images, etc. to 200th folder.

Images are not in one folder, instead images are separated in 200 folder and in every folder are cca 4k images.

Ant this script generating masks from this 200 folders into 1 folder.

dataset defined:

```
class SynthTextDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, train, transforms):
        self.transforms = transforms
        self.synt_text_path = "/home/SynthText/"

        gt_mat_path = os.path.join(self.synt_text_path, "gt.mat")

        self.gt_mat = scipy.io.loadmat(gt_mat_path)

        self.train = train
        self.val_size = 1000
        self.train_size = self.gt_mat['imnames'].size #- 1000

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if not self.train:
            i = self.train_size + i

        image_path = self.gt_mat['imnames'][0][i][0]
        full_image_path = os.path.join(self.synt_text_path, image_path)

        image = Image.open(full_image_path)

        if number_of_gt_mat_annotations_is_zero(self.gt_mat['wordBB'][0][i]):
            empty_target = create_empty_target(i, image.size)

            if self.transforms is not None:
                image, target = self.transforms(image, empty_target)
            # if self.transforms is not None:
            #     image = self.transforms(image)

            return image, empty_target

        number_of_annotations = self.gt_mat['wordBB'][0][i].shape[2]
        rotated_boxes = get_rotated_boxes(self.gt_mat['wordBB'][0][i])
        boxes = get_boxes(self.gt_mat['wordBB'][0][i])

        target = {}
        target["image_id"] = torch.tensor(i)
        target["labels"] = torch.ones(number_of_annotations, dtype=torch.int64)
        target["iscrowd"] = torch.tensor([False for i in range(number_of_annotations)], dtype=torch.uint8)
        target["boxes"] = boxes
        target["area"] = calculate_areas(boxes)
        target["masks"] = torch.tensor(np.array(get_masks(rotated_boxes, image.size)), dtype=torch.uint8)

        # if self.transforms is not None:
        #     image = self.transforms(image)
        if self.transforms is not None:
            image, target = self.transforms(image, target)

        return image, target

    def __len__(self):
        if self.train:
            return self.train_size
        else:
            return self.val_size

    def set_length(self, length):
        self.length = length
```

genertating masks:

I don't know how to include `gt.mat['imnames']` in `cv2.imwrite()`

```
dataset = SynthTextDataset("/home/SynthText/" ,get_transform(train=True))

dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, collate_fn=utils.collate_fn, shuffle=False)
data_iter = iter(dataloader)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

for i, data in enumerate(dataloader):
    image, target = data
    image = image[0]
    target = target[0]
    image = np.array(image)
    image = np.swapaxes(image, 0, 1)
    image = np.swapaxes(image, 1, 2)
    #axes[0].imshow(image)

    masks_merged = np.zeros_like(masks[0], dtype=np.uint8)
    for mask in masks:
        mask = mask.numpy()
        mask = mask.astype('uint8')
        masks_merged += mask

    masks_merged[masks_merged > 0] = 255
    #print(type(masks_merged)) -> numpy.ndarray
    #axes[1].imshow(masks_merged)

    #cv2.imwrite(f'Matlab/{SynthTextDataset.full_image_path} '+str(i)+".jpg", masks_merged)
    cv2.imwrite(f'Matlab/'+str(i)+".jpg", masks_merged)

    # plt.savefig("im_" + str(i) + ".jpg")

    axes[0].clear()
    axes[1].clear()
```

Currently masks are generating like this:

[image]

But I want names like this, so that every mask have identical name as rgb image.
[image]

Comment: You EXPLICITLY decide the name of the file: `cv2.imwrite(f'Matlab/'+str(i)+".jpg", masks_merged)`. They are called `str(i)+".jpg"`. There is nothing stopping you from changing that....

Comment: Ok I know what are you talking, but I tried change `f'Matlab/{gt.mat['imnames']'+".jpg"` and I can't access `imnames` variable that are in Matlab file. I don't know how to implement this